# Excel – locale-independent Number Format

Tags: excel

I looking for a **number format** that is **locale-independent**.

Let's say that I want that my Excel file use an **a** character as a thousand separator and a **b** character as a decimal separator on every computer (so this question is not about local Excel settings). The second wish is that the number has always two decimal places.

Can I do this only with a **number format** without **VB code**?

---

After some attempts, I came to this format: **###\a###\a##0\b.00**.

```
1234567.89 > 1a234a567b.89
```

The problems are:
I must repeat **###\a** section and I can not get rid of **dot decimal separator** (the decimal places are not taken into account without the dot character).

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this with the Excel custom formatting.   The problem will be that Excel gets the decimal separator from the system (the "Regional and Language" settings in Windows).   If you must use this format a workaround that might work would be to multiply all your values by 100 and use something like `###\a###\a###\a###"b"00`, but this seems to me to have too many pitfalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do this only with a number format without VB code?

No.

Even if you can get your separator characters inserted, you will not be able to remove the decimal separator.

The decimal separator is displayed in the cell whenever it is included in custom number display format settings.